# Chef - Multiple sources for remote_directory

Tags: chef-infra

In puppet it is possible to pass an array of sources for the file block for a directory to copy from multiple sources to the intended directory.

In chef's remote_directory source attribute only seems to accept a single source. Is there any other attribute to pass several sources to be aggregated to the directory?

I guess I could have two remote_directory resources one after the other and specify the different sources, but I'm not sure if it would clear and rewrite the directory with latest resource's contents.

Answer (score 0):

As the `remote_directory` resource intent is to ensure the directory on the machine is the same (content included) as the directory in the cookbook defining it.

So you can't have 2 sources for the same directory in the same cookbook, and redifining it in two cookbooks will end up with the lastest overwriting the first one.

So yes its a different paradigm than Puppet.

In chef you may wish to have a look at the [ark](https://github.com/burtlo/ark) cookbook to uncompress a zip/tar file to a specific destination, this way you should be able to make a directory from two sources.

Another way would be to use 2 remote_directory and then an execute block to merge them. But you still have the risk of one overlapping contents.

And last if you have some different files, use `remote_file` ([doc](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_remote_file.html)) within a loop to define each file like:

```
%W(file1.ext file2 file3.ext}.each do |f|
  remote_file f do
    source "<source path http/ftp>/#{f}"
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode "0644"
  end
end
```

You could even set your file list with checksum for each file in an attribute hash and iterate over it, but I'm not sure it is your intent, I'll update if needed.